# Excess JSON response

Tags: php, mysql, json

My JSON response seems to have excess keys in it. Any idea why?

Here is an excerpt from the JSON response:

```
{
      "0": "1",
      "id": "1",
      "1": "XX University",
      "name": "XX University",
      "2": "http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/xxUniversity.png",
      "backgroundImageUrl": "http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/XXUniversityLogo.png",
      "3": "http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/xxUniversity.png",
      "logoImageUrl": "http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/XXUniversityLogo.png"
    },
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT * from $entity"; //Bad security,for a different question
    $results = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    //Parse to JSON
    $json=array();

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        $json[]=$row;
    }

    //Close connection
    mysqli_close($con);

    //Encode and send response as JSON (using the entity type as a parameter)
    //echo json_encode(array($entity => $json), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    echo json_encode(array ($entity =>$json));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is `mysqli_fetch_array`. You want to pass `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as a second parameter.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $json[]=$row;
}
```

[From the docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants **MYSQLI_ASSOC**, **MYSQLI_NUM**, or **MYSQLI_BOTH**.
>
> By using the **MYSQLI_ASSOC** constant this function will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_assoc(), while **MYSQLI_NUM** will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_row() function. The final option **MYSQLI_BOTH** will create a single array with the attributes of both.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) per default retrieves both numeric and named index.

You have to specify an additional parameters to get only the desired ones.

- MYSQLI_ASSOC retrieves the named array,
- MYSQLI_NUM   retrieves just the integer indexed one
- MYSQLI_BOTH  retrieves both :)